# How to add an extension to a file copy activity with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

The datasets that I ingest from a REST API endpoint do not include the .JSON extension to the files (even though they're JSON files). Therefore, can someone let me know where I can add a .json extension from the following scenarios

Scenario 1.
Adding .JSON to the relativeURL
[image]

Scenario 2
Adding .JSON to the SINK
[image]

Scenario 3
Adding .JSON to SOURCE - However, I don't think this is possible
[image]

Can someone please take a look at the three scenarios and let me know if I can add .JSON extension to any of those methods?

Comment: in your sink use concat with the filename to add the .json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **@Scott Mildenberger**, we can provide the name of the file and its extension from the sink dataset.

- The following is a demonstration of the same. I have a file called `sample` without extension.
- In the sink dataset, you can simply `concat` the extension to your filename (If it is just a single file, you can directly give the required name with extension directly). I have used the following dynamic content (fileName parameter value is `req_filename`).

```
@concat(dataset().fileName,'.json')
```

[image]

- The following file would be generated in the sink.

[image]